# Nivo Slider - Not to resize the images when Maximize or Minimize

Tags: html, css

I have downloaded NIVO SLIDER and it's working perfectly but the problem is that i don't want the slider to resize.
// Detect Window Resize

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        slider.children('img').width(slider.width());
        sliderImg.attr('src', vars.currentImage.attr('src'));
        sliderImg.stop().height('auto');
        $('.nivo-slice').remove();
        $('.nivo-box').remove();
    });
```

Comment: Go google `picture slideshow jquery`

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [slider.js](http://sliderjs.org/). This one seems pretty decent. Anyhow you have to style it using css to make that prev and next button to appear the way you want. Its no big deal actually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pure css slider which looks quite need. But @Doan Cuong is right, that would have solved itself with a an easy google lookup

http://wowslider.com/de/css-slider-aqua-flip-demo.html

Answer (score 1):

You may start with one of these jquery slider plugins:

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/03/jquery-slider.html

or these responsive ones:

http://webdesignledger.com/resources/8-responsive-jquery-slider-plugins